# C# console Abort multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, console, break, cancellationtokensource

I work on console version of link tester.
I start the function on multiple threads but I can't cancel them by key pressing.
Have an idea how I can do that ?

```
try
{
    Thread[] tr = new Thread[Variables.Threads];
    int i = 0;
    while (i < Variables.Threads && Variables.running)
    {
        tr[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Program.Runner));
        i++;
    }
    //Start each thread  
    foreach (Thread x in tr)
    {
        x.Start();
    }
    //Console.ReadKey();  

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (Colorful.Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
        Variables.running = false;
        foreach (Thread x in tr)
        {
            x.Abort();
        }
        Program.Menu();
    });

}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

EDIT : When my threads are a near of end, all of my app don't move after

Comment: How are you blocking your console application from terminating? With your given code the console application would just simply end, and nothing would stop it.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this? `while (tr.Any(x => x.IsAlive));` //wait for the threads to shutdown

Comment: Thanks for ure help but my research are about aborting not waiting.
I'm try to stop all threads by key pressure.

Comment: I meant to wait for abortion to be complete, abort only singals the thread to abort but doesn’t abort it immediately, so you may need to wait for it, what my suggested code does.

Answer (score 0):

The console is a not a good environment to start learning multitasking, much less multithreading. My advise to learning Multitasking - and especially Multithreading - is the BackgroundWorker in a WindowsForms applciation. The event queue does the main thing of keeping your application alive, without blocking I/O. And while the BackgroundWorker is horribly dated and should be removed from production code, it is pretty good training wheels.

Also your current code is swallowing exceptions, [including fatal ones](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/). This is a cardinal sin of [exception handling](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET). Do not do that.

At the end of the day, you can only do cancelation checking and progress reporting between distinct lines of code. In this BGW example, I had the advantage that I had to write all the loops anyway - so deep cancelation checking and progress reporting was in the cards. But if you use "somebody elses code", chances are high you have to wait for one function call to return before you can report and check.

```
#region Primenumbers
private void btnPrimStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!bgwPrim.IsBusy)
    {
        //Prepare ProgressBar and Textbox
        int temp = (int)nudPrim.Value;
        pgbPrim.Maximum = temp;
        tbPrim.Text = "";

        //Start processing
        bgwPrim.RunWorkerAsync(temp);
    }
}

private void btnPrimCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bgwPrim.IsBusy)
    {
        bgwPrim.CancelAsync();
    }
}

private void bgwPrim_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int highestToCheck = (int)e.Argument;
    //Get a reference to the BackgroundWorker running this code
    //for Progress Updates and Cancelation checking
    BackgroundWorker thisWorker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

    //Create the list that stores the results and is returned by DoWork
    List<int> Primes = new List<int>();


    //Check all uneven numbers between 1 and whatever the user choose as upper limit
    for(int PrimeCandidate=1; PrimeCandidate < highestToCheck; PrimeCandidate+=2)
    {
        //Report progress
        thisWorker.ReportProgress(PrimeCandidate);
        bool isNoPrime = false;

        //Check if the Cancelation was requested during the last loop
        if (thisWorker.CancellationPending)
        {
            //Tell the Backgroundworker you are canceling and exit the for-loop
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }

        //Determin if this is a Prime Number
        for (int j = 3; j < PrimeCandidate && !isNoPrime; j += 2)
        {
            if (PrimeCandidate % j == 0)
                isNoPrime = true;
        }

        if (!isNoPrime)
            Primes.Add(PrimeCandidate);
    }

    //Tell the progress bar you are finished
    thisWorker.ReportProgress(highestToCheck);

    //Save Return Value
    e.Result = Primes.ToArray();
}

private void bgwPrim_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    pgbPrim.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void bgwPrim_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    pgbPrim.Value = pgbPrim.Maximum;
    this.Refresh();

    if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
    {
        //Show the Result
        int[] Primes = (int[])e.Result;

        StringBuilder sbOutput = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (int Prim in Primes)
        {
            sbOutput.Append(Prim.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        tbPrim.Text = sbOutput.ToString();
    }
    else 
    {
        tbPrim.Text = "Operation canceled by user or Exception";
    }
}
#endregion
```

However in your case, Multi**threading** seems unesseary. Multi**tasking** without Threads would propably be better. Threads only help if you got a *CPU bound* task. And "checking links" sounds like a *Network bound* task. Threads have some extra headaches that you are better off avoiding.

Comment: Thanks for all information.
I have already used BackgroundWorker in UI app but I was hoping to find a way for console mode.
You have an example for convert my threading method to multitasking?
Sorry, I'm relatively newbie in this place ^^ '

Comment: @hackhacky One issue is keeping the application alive, but without blocking the I/O. For that the GUI Event loop is simply perfect. Without it, you have to replicate that feature. | For Multitasking, I can only point you to a async/await toutorial. It results in teh compiler and runtime taking care of a lot of the plumbing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: Thanks again dude, gonna to check this